# Protocolo TCP/IP em Linux e Windows

Tags: c++, sistema-operacional, tcp

A estrutura do protocolo TCP/IP pode variar de **Windows** para **Linux** ou até mesmo de linguagem para linguagem? os conhecimentos adquiridos sobre TCP/IP na linguagem C++ podem também ser levados em consideração em Python?

Abraços

Comment: Não, protocolo é agnóstico ao sistema ou linguagem de programação. O que pode mudar é a forma que foi implementado para trabalhar com o protocolo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grande parte dos protocolos de comunicação usados na internet, incluindo a suite TCP/IP, são definidos por documentos conhecidos como Request For Comments, nome sempre abreviado para RFC [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments). Sendo assim, a definição dos protocolos não depende nem do sistema operacional nem da linguagem utilizada.

A *implementação* dos protocolos pode ter pequenas diferenças entre sistemas operacionais. Estas diferenças no entanto não interferem, de maneira geral, na inter-operabilidade entre os diferentes sistemas operacionais. Prova disso é a internet, onde sistemas diferentes se comunicam sem problema usando os protocolos TCP/IP.